# how to write inner join a selected table query in hibernate.ejb

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, db2, inner-join

I have a query working fine:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(
        "select o.deviceName, o.deviceOs, o.loginOn, e.username, e.name, e.idNo from LoginHistory o, User e ");
    query.append(" where o.userId = e.userId");
Query q = getEm().createQuery(query.toString());
```

This `createQuery()` will go to createQuery() in class `org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl`.

I want to edit the query to get the last login for each user. The following SQL query can run in a db2 command successfully:

```
select m1.*, m2.*
from tibs.LoginHistory m1 inner join (
    select userId, max(loginOn) as loginOn from tibs.LoginHistory group by userId
    ) m2
on m1.userId = m2.userId and m1.loginOn = m2.loginOn;
```

But when I try to apply this in my code above, it will hit `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:` at `(` after `inner join`.

Code is something like:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(
        "select o.deviceName, o.deviceOs, o.loginOn, e.username, e.name, e.cif, e.idNo from LoginHistory o, ECUser e ");
    query.append("inner join (select o2.userId, o2.max(loginOn) as loginOn from LoginHistory group by userId) o2 ");
    query.append("on o.userId = o2.userId and o.loginOn = o2.loginOn");
    query.append(" where o.userId = e.userId");
```

Is this workable in this way? If yes, what syntax should I use?

Or does Hibernate not accept this, and I need to do it in another way?

Add on**
Even I change my query to this, still the same:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(
        "select o.deviceName, o.deviceOs, o.loginOn, e.username, e.name, e.cif, e.idNo from LoginHistory o, ECUser e ");
    query.append("inner join (select o2.userId, o2.max(loginOn) as loginOn from LoginHistory o2 group by userId) ");
    query.append("on o.userId = o2.userId and o.loginOn = o2.loginOn");
    query.append(" where o.userId = e.userId");
```

Comment: If you are using Java 15+, you can use multi line String (Text Blocks). https://www.infoq.com/articles/java-text-blocks/

Comment: What does "in this way" mean? [mre] Giving "something like" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the inner query should be as follows (note position of `o2`):

```
(select o2.userId, o2.max(loginOn) as loginOn from LoginHistory o2 group by userId)
```

Please name variables appropriately to facilitate comprehension.
It would be helpful if `o2` was renamed to `lh`, since it represents `LoginHistory` entity.

```
(select lh.userId, lh.max(loginOn) as loginOn from LoginHistory lh group by userId)
```

Comment: Hi Nice Books, I change to the one you mention, still the same. Edited in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
select o.deviceName, o.deviceOs, o.loginOn, e.username, e.name, e.idNo
from LoginHistory o, User e 
where o.id = (select max(lh.id) from LoginHistory lh where lh.userId = e.userId)
```